# Google Sheets API v4 Spreadsheets.Values.Update returns ERROR 404:Requested entity was not found

Tags: java

I am trying to update a cell on google sheet using Spreadsheets.Values.Update method. I am able to access to the google sheet and read data back, but when using Spreadsheets.Values.Update method, I got the following error:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404
>   Not Found

```
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Requested entity was not found.",
  "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

below is the code. I used the quickstart code from google developers guide to create authentication.

```
/**
 * Application name.
 */
public class Quickstart {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

/**
 * Directory to store user credentials for this application.
 */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

/**
 * Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}.
 */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/**
 * Global instance of the JSON factory.
 */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/**
 * Global instance of the HTTP transport.
 */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * <p/>
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private static Sheets service;

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 *
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
            Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                    JSON_FACTORY,
                    clientSecrets,
                    SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();

    Credential credential =
            new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver())
                    .authorize("user");

    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
 *
 * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();

    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
            JSON_FACTORY,
            credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}

private static void updateCell(String spreadsheetId, String range, 
    String newData) throws Exception {
    service = getSheetsService();
    ValueRange aValueRange = new ValueRange();
    aValueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
    aValueRange.setRange(range);
    List<List<Object>> dataArr = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    List<Object> cellData = new ArrayList<Object>();
    cellData.add(newData);
    dataArr.add(cellData);
    aValueRange.setValues(dataArr);
    System.out.println("\nNew value range: " + aValueRange);
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, 
    aValueRange).setValueInputOption("RAW").execute();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        String updatedSheetId = "123456";
        String range = "F5:F5";
        updateCell(updatedSheetId, range, "inUse"); 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out that the "requested entity not found" error was caused by the invalid spreadsheetId.
So I assume that "requested entity not found" error means that the server received the request but could not find resource requested or that it doesn't exist

Comment: But how do you fix the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you are using the valid spreadsheet id and a valid scope for accessing spreadsheet. You can refer the valid scopes from google documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

I was also facing similar kind of issue when using `drive.file` scope but after changing to spreadsheet scope, issue resolved.

Comment: Same here, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` was not enough to call spreadsheets:get, needed the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` scope.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I don't know where the spreadsheet id is Then I realized it's in its URL
[image]

Comment: This was the right answer for me. Thanks mate.